# Default constructor setting random value

Tags: visual-studio, class, c++11, random, default-constructor

I'm writing a simple class for atoms objects. Here's what I've written so far:

```
#include <random>

class Atom {
    int mSpin;

public:
    Atom();
    Atom(int);
    Atom(const Atom&);
    ~Atom() {}

    Atom& operator= (const Atom &atom);
};
```

And the .cpp file:

```
include "Atom.h"

Atom::Atom() {
}
Atom::Atom(int spin) : mSpin(spin) {}
Atom::Atom(const Atom& copy) : mSpin(copy.mSpin) {}

/*  OPERATORS  */

Atom& Atom::operator= (const Atom &copy) {
    mSpin = copy.mSpin;
    return *this;
}
```

I want to make the default constructor such that when I'm creating an object, mSpin will be randomly set as 1 or -1. I understand how to do it with rand() but rand() is not very good and I'd like to use . I'm kind of confused by the use of , even after reading the documentation and other answers on here. 
Usually I'd do something like this:

```
#include <random>
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,1);
int random_number = dis(gen);
```

but I'm not sure how to use it inside a class. I tried placing it inside the default constructor but I think it's wrong because it would seed each time I create an atom?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the random device and generator static members of the Atom class. This way, like global variables, they are initialized only once for the duration of your program.

```
class Atom {
  // declaration
  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::mt13397 gen;

  ...
};

// definition - this must be in Atom.cpp
std::random_device Atom::rd;
std::mt13397 Atom::gen(Atom::rd());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd up vote your answer but don't have enough reputation to do it.

Comment: No problem! But since you are the one who posted the question, you can mark it as the accepted answer. By the way, good luck with your Ising models!

Comment: Is it now the accepted answer? I hope so! Was it so obvious it was about the Ising model? :D

Comment: Yes, it's now the accepted answer. Note, you can designate another answer as the accepted one at any time. And yes, it is quite obviously an Ising model to a physicist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate to a function in the cpp file:

```cpp
namespace {                                                                                                                                                  
    random_device rd;                                                                                                                                            
    mt19937 gen(rd());                                                                                                                                           
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                            
int spin() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return dis(gen) == 0 ? -1 : 1;                                                                                                                           
}
```

Delete your implementation of the default CTOR.

And to follow the rule 'initialise all variables' change Atom.hpp:

```
int spin(); // Return -1 or 1, randomly

class Atom {
    int mSpin = spin();
public:
    Atom() = default;
    ...
};
```

Then, in your cpp file, delete your Atom default CTOR implementation and move 'spin' function definition out of the anonymous namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'll be using the other one because I find it easier. I'd upvote (don't have enough reputations) it for the ternary operator, which I didn't know before.